# variable looping

Tags: excel, vba, loops, variables

i am attempting to create a code to help do some design work.
i want my code to be able to read a radius of a circle e.g. 40m
we have rules that say we can use multiples of 12m to achieve this e.g. 12+12+12+12 but this does not satisify the issue so we need to then replace one of those numbers with a smaller number starting at 10m so equation would look like this 12+12+12+10 and if that still doesnt work change a different number so equation will look like this 12+12+10+12 we need this to loop until we can get it to 40m(subject to change could be upwards of 93m just using 40m for simplicity)

is there a way to set up variables that add to each other to get to the desired result but loop through changing the numbers until a desired result is hit.

to add to this the final number can be a a close estimate as long as it is 0.5m long minimum
e.g. if our radius is equal to 41.7 then no whole number will satisfy this so my intention is to have a loop that finds the best close answer and then an additional bit of code that will then adjust the final number

i have no idea where to start so havnt tried much

i expect to be able to input the radius, number of potential numbers to be used aka its not always goign to be 4 different numbers it could be more or less we know roughly how many we need just not the order they need to be in

the output we expect to have the cells on excel filled out with the length per item in a different cell e.g. 12m in one cell , 12m in a different cell, 12m in a different cell and then 4m in a different cell as this will fit our requirements.

if there is a way to loop through numbers until a desired number is hit that would be ideal just not sure how i would write that in code

Comment: `Do Until`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doloop-statement https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/do-until-loop.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As others already noted, it's not fully clear what you need.
Anyway, the code below distributes the radius (B1) in the number (B3) of addends that are multiples of the divisor you specify in B2. Until the remainder gets less than the divisor.

```
Sub distribute()
Dim radius As Integer, divisor As Integer, addends As Integer
Dim times As Integer
Dim i As Integer

    radius = Range("B1").Value
    divisor = Range("B2").Value
    addends = Range("B3").Value
    times = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(radius / divisor / addends, 1)
    
    For i = 1 To addends
        If radius > divisor * times Then
            Cells(5, i).Value = divisor * times
            radius = radius - divisor * times
        Else
            Cells(5, i).Value = radius
            radius = 0
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```